# Can't Use PHP to process Paypal IPN because of Windows Server box. What is the standard alternative?

Tags: php, mysql, database, paypal, paypal-ipn

Evidently PHP is not the script to use with a Windows hosted web domain...a surprise I discovered when I couldn't do file_puts or mail() calls in the simplest of PHP scripts.

I'm parsing Paypal IPN information and pushing that data to a mySQL DB, and occasionally send an e-mail if the process encounters an error. I've got it functioning in PHP for a Linux hosted web domain, but evidently this doesn't work with a Windows hosted web domain.

**What's the best language/web standard practice language to replicate my PHP IPN handler in?** Or, alternatively, have I been misinformed by the GoDaddy support guy and there are easy workarounds for PHP & a Windows server?

I'm fairly new to the web developing world, so forgive me if this is a 'duh' answer. I just don't want to accidentally pick a totally obscure language with no re-usability value.

Thanks!

Comment: Those functions have nothing to do with the OS. They should both work if configured correctly regardless of platform. *"I just don't want to accidentally pick a totally obscure language with no re-usability value*" - I wouldn't ever describe [PHP as relatively obscure](http://www.langpop.com/).

Comment: You didn't pick a totally obscure language, but you will hear that PHP is a terrible language, usually with references pointing back many many versions ago. You can use `file_puts` and `mail` on a Winodws Server, but it comes down to the server configuration. It's possible that they have set their server to be a bit locked down for security, which is a risk you run with shared hosting.

Comment: @MikeB Keep in mind, LangPop hasn't had its statistics updated in about 20 months. So the numbers may have skewed a bit in that time. Example, I wouldn't be surprised if Ruby has surpassed PHP, or at least significantly closed the gap.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 Does that make PHP any more obscure or reusable? http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html Updated Jan 2013.

Comment: @MikeB Not necessarily, but if enough market share is lost, at some point the answer to the question would become yes. Thank you for the link to the more updated statistics.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your setup, it is definitely not a PHP/windows issue, because I am using paypal IPN with no problem. The problem with the mail is probably because you dont have a mail server set up in the php configuration. In this case you need to use custom SMTP to send mail. An answer on how to do that is given here:
[Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)
OR alternatively change the smtp settings in your php.ini, or using ini_set() if its allowed. the issues with the file_puts can be numerous, so you would have to at least post the error that  you are getting. But again that is not a php/windows problem, it has to do with your configuration...